# How do I apply evolutions to test database in Play framework

Tags: playframework

I noticed couple of issues while running in test mode in play framework.

after modifying application.conf for enabling test database, and if the test database is not created, it automatically picks up dev database, I don't know if this is correct.

I was not able to apply evolutions to test database.
How do I apply evolutions exclusively to test database, as I created test database long time after I started with dev database.

The following is the content of application.conf

```
%test.application.mode=dev<br/>
%test.db.url=postgres://postgres:Passw0rd@localhost/dashboard_test<br/>
%test.jpa.ddl=create-drop
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the command

```
play evolutions:apply --%test
```